# How can I use Automator Service to create a .zip file from two original files using the same name?

Tags: automator

[image]

Look at the image above. What I am trying to do is create a service in Automator that will allow me to select two of the files, such as

3LW And Loon - I Do (Wanna Get Close To You) (Duet).cdg
AND
3LW And Loon - I Do (Wanna Get Close To You) (Duet).mp3

And compress those two files into a .zip entitled

3LW And Loon - I Do (Wanna Get Close To You) (Duet).zip

And then be able to move down to

38 Special - Hold On Loosely.cdg
AND
38 Special - Hold On Loosely.mp3

and compress them into a .zip entitled

38 Special - Hold On Loosely.zip

Is this at all possible? I have no idea how to do this. Any help at all will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is doable, and in more then one way too.

The following describes a minimal no frills *workflow*:

- In **Automator**, select: **File** > **New** > **Service**
- Set: **Service receives selected files or folders** in **Finder**
- Add the following **Actions**:
- **Run Shell Script**

  - Settings: **Shell: /bin/bash** *and* **Pass input: as arguments**
  - Replace all of the *default code* with just: `echo "$(basename "${1%.*}")"`

    - This returns the *filename* portion of the first *file*, sans its *extension*, and is what **Set Value of Variable** gets set to.
- **Set Value of Variable**

  - Click, **Variable: New variable...** and give it an appropriate name, e.g.: **ZipFileName**
- **Get Selected Finder Items**

  - Set **Options** to: **[√] Ignore this action's input**

    - Note that this creates a wanted break between this *action* and the previous *action*.
- **Create Archive**

  - Set **Save as:** *to* **ZipFileName** by drag and drop of the *variable* from the **Variable** section at the bottom of the *workflow pane*.
  - Set **Where:** *to* **Same Folder as Input**.

Update to add moving files to the **Trash**:

- Add these additional **Actions**:
- **Get Selected Finder Items**

  - Set **Options** to: **[√] Ignore this action's input**

    - Note that this creates a wanted break between this *action* and the previous *action*.
- **Move Finder Items to Trash**
- Save the **Automator Service Workflow** giving it an appropriate name, e.g.: **Compress File Set**

Now in **Finder**, select **two** of the **matching filenames**, *sans having different extensions*, then *right-click* and *select* **Compress File Set**, from the *services* section of the *context menu*.

**Note:** This minimal no frills Automator Service Workflow employs no error checking. It relies on one to properly select the two matching filenames, sans the differing extensions, to be compressed together in a zip archive of the first file's filename, sans its extension.

See the second *workflow*, below the picture, that employs conditional error checking and handling and has some features the no frills *workflow* doesn't have.

[image: Automator Service Workflow]

---

**Second Automator Service Workflow**

The following *workflow* has conditional error checking and handling. It can be used instead of the no frills *workflow* above:

It uses as single **Run Shell Script** *action* to handle the entire process.

- In **Automator**, select: **File** > **New** > **Service**
- Set: **Service receives selected files or folders** in **Finder**
- Add a **Run Shell Script** *Action*

  - Settings: **Shell: /bin/bash** *and* **Pass input: as arguments**
  - Replace all of the *default code* with the *code* show further below.
- Save the **Automator Service Workflow** giving it an appropriate name, e.g.: **Compress File Set**

Now in **Finder**, select **two** of the **matching filenames**, *sans having different extensions*, then *right-click* and *select* **Compress File Set**, from the *services* section of the *context menu*.

This **Automator Service Workflow** employs the following conditional error checking and handling:

- Makes sure only two items are selected in **Finder**.
- Makes sure both files have the same filename, sans extension.
- Makes sure the filename extensions match the expected type, 'cdg' and 'mp3'.
- Employs appropriate error handling if processing errors out.
- Is coded to be able to give both verbal and visual messages as appropriate.

  - Is set to use **Notification Center** for visual messages, but can be easily changed to speak the messages too.

**Frills:**

- Makes the same sounds when compressing and or moving the files to the **Trash** in **Finder**.

  - Can be set to play this event sound or not, default is to play it.
- Can directly delete the files instead of placing them in the **Trash**.

  - The default is to move the files to the **Trash**, make this setting change only of you totally understand the finality of this action.

The script has two **Functions** and a **Main** section.

- **function CompressSelectedFiles ()**

  - This handles the grunt work and has the settings for the compress event sound and moving files to the **Trash**.
- **function NotifyUserMessage()**

  - This handles notifying the user with the various messages and the settings for the type of notifications, verbal and or visual.
- **Main**

  - This handles the main logic flow validating conditions are met before processing. 
    This section does not have user setting as that within the two functions have.
- **Read comments throughout the script so as to modify it features appropriately.**

**Code** for **Run Shell Script** *Action*:

```
#!/bin/bash

    ### Functions ###

function CompressSelectedFiles () {

        # Change to the target directory, 
        # or notify user of failure and exit.

    if ! cd "$(dirname "$1")"; then
        NotifyUserMessage 'nochgdir'
        exit
    fi
        # Set the two filenames to variables.

    f1="$(basename "$1")"
    f2="$(basename "$2")"

        # Check to see if the target zip archive 
        # already exists, and if not, create it.

    if [[ ! -e "${f1%.*}.zip" ]]; then
            # Syntax: zip [options] zipfile file ...
        if ! zip "${f1%.*}.zip" "${f1}" "${f2}"; then
            NotifyUserMessage 'ziperror'
            exit
        fi

    #       # The following lines of code mimic Finder's Compress command
    #       # as to numerically incrementing an archive's filename. It has
    #       # been commented out as the user requested to delete the files
    #       # after I wrote this. I've left it, in case it's found useful.
    #
    # else
    #       # The zip archive already exists!
    #       # Numerically increment the zip filename.
    #   n=2
    #   for f in ${f1%.*} *.zip; do
    #       if [[ "${f1%.*} $n.zip" == "$f" ]]; then
    #           n="$(( n + 1 ))"
    #       fi
    #   done
    #       # Syntax: zip [options] zipfile file ...
    #   if ! zip "${f1%.*} $n.zip" "${f1}" "${f2}"; then
    #       NotifyUserMessage 'ziperror'
    #       exit
    #   fi

            # Make the same event sound Finder does when compressing files.
            # Note: Despite its name, this *is* the sound made by Finder when compressing files.
            # If you do not want to hear it, set 'playthis=1' to 'playthis=0'.

        playthis=1

        [[ $playthis -eq 1 ]] && afplay "/System/Library/Components/CoreAudio.component/Contents/SharedSupport/SystemSounds/system/Volume Mount.aif"
        [[ $playthis -eq 1 ]] && sleep 1    # Pause to allow time between event sounds.
    fi

        # The following was added per user request.
        #
        # Move File Set to the Trash. So you can then use
        # Put Back from the Trash in Finder, if necessary.
        # Default is to use the Trash, setting 'trash=1'.
        #
        # If you don't want to put the files in the Trash, 
        # just delete them directly, then set 'delete=1'
        # and set 'trash=0' when setting 'delete=1'.
        #
        # WARNING: Setting 'delete=1', this method
        #          is immediate and irreversible.

    trash=1
    delete=0

    [[ $trash -eq 1 ]] && osascript -e "set theFiles to {}" \
                                    -e "set the end of theFiles to POSIX file \"$1\"" \
                                    -e "set the end of theFiles to POSIX file \"$2\"" \
                                    -e "tell application \"Finder\" to move theFiles to trash"

    [[ $delete -eq 1 ]] && rm "$1" "$2"

        # Notify user processing is finished.

    NotifyUserMessage 'finished'
}   


function NotifyUserMessage() {

        # Set servicename='' to the name of this service.

    servicename='Compress File Set'

    # As currently set, messages are sent to the Notification Center.
    # If you want a verbal message, change the value of 'verbal=0'
    # to 'verbal=1'. If your OS version is older and doesn't support  
    # Notification Center from scripts, e.g. OS X 10.8, then change
    # 'visual=1' to 'visual=0'. Whichever your preference is, set 0
    # for false and 1 for true.

    verbal=0
    visual=1

    case $1 in
        selected )
                msg='This service requires two files to be selected.'
                [[ $verbal -eq 1 ]] && say "$msg"
                [[ $visual -eq 1 ]] && osascript -e "display notification \"$msg\" with title \"$servicename Error\""
                ;;
        filenames )
                msg='The filenames, sans extensions, are mismatched.'
                [[ $verbal -eq 1 ]] && say "$msg"
                [[ $visual -eq 1 ]] && osascript -e "display notification \"$msg\" with title \"$servicename Error\""
                ;;
        extensions )
                msg='One or both file extensions are not the expected type.'
                [[ $verbal -eq 1 ]] && say "$msg"
                [[ $visual -eq 1 ]] && osascript -e "display notification \"$msg\" with title \"$servicename Error\""
                ;;
        nochgdir )
                msg='An error occurred while trying to change directory.'
                [[ $verbal -eq 1 ]] && say "$msg"
                [[ $visual -eq 1 ]] && osascript -e "display notification \"$msg\" with title \"$servicename Error\""
                ;;
        ziperror )
                msg='An error occurred while compressing the files.'
                [[ $verbal -eq 1 ]] && say "$msg"
                [[ $visual -eq 1 ]] && osascript -e "display notification \"$msg\" with title \"$servicename Error\""
                ;;
        finished )
                msg='The selected files have been compressed.'
                [[ $verbal -eq 1 ]] && sleep 1  # Pause so as not to step on previous event sound.
                [[ $verbal -eq 1 ]] && say "$msg"
                [[ $visual -eq 1 ]] && osascript -e "display notification \"$msg\" with title \"$servicename\""
                ;;
    esac
}


    ### Main ###

        # Validate Conditions #

    # Make sure only two items are selected in Finder.

if [[ $# -eq 2 ]]; then

        # Make sure both files have the same filename, sans extension.

    if [[ ${1%.*} == "${2%.*}" ]]; then

            # Make sure the filename extensions match the expected type, 'cdg' and 'mp3'.

        if [[ ${1##*.} =~ [cC][dD][gG] ]] && [[ ${2##*.} =~ [mM][pP]3 ]]; then

                # All conditions met, create zip archive.

            CompressSelectedFiles "$1" "$2"

        elif [[ ${2##*.} =~ [cC][dD][gG] ]] && [[ ${1##*.} =~ [mM][pP]3 ]]; then

                # All conditions met, create zip archive.

            CompressSelectedFiles "$1" "$2"

        else
            NotifyUserMessage 'extensions'
        fi
    else
        NotifyUserMessage 'filenames'
    fi
else
    NotifyUserMessage 'selected'
fi
```

Comment: EXCELLENT! Thank you SO much. This works perfectly... One last question; is there a way to add a command to delete the files I've archived? Meaning, I run this service, it creates the .zip and then deletes the .cdg and .mp3 file that were compressed?

Comment: @Robert M. Cluesman, I've updated the original workflow per your comment and have also added a second workflow that personally I'd use instead of the updated original, but that's for you to decide.

Comment: @Robert M. Cluesman, I don't know whether or not you've seen the updated answer however, I've just updated the second workflow, I moved the `exit` _commands_ out of `function NotifyUserMessage()` to `function CompressSelectedFiles` and placed `exit` after the `NotifyUserMessage` _function call_, where they should have been. So it you're using the second workflow then be sure to replace the code with a fresh copy of the now current code. BTW I'd be nice if you'd mark my answer as the accepted answer, click the √ on the left. :)